# Adding responder of a Google Form as a section on the form

Tags: google-apps-script

I have never used Google Apps Script so please let me know if there are similar questions.
I have a petition type Google Form. The form collects responders name, email and department. I want to add all responders' names and departments in the format of "Name, Department" back onto the form automatically as a separate block after the questions of the form.
How do I do this? So after all that, the form should look like the image below. [image: Description of how the Google Form should look like]

Comment: So what I understand is that you have `Form A`, in the first page you ask for responders `Name`, `Email` and `Deparment` and you want to drag that information to the next page in a new section but within the same `Form A` or it would be a different Google Form? If this is not the case please give a more detailed example of what you are looking for. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: I have tried to improve the language a bit and added what I was hoping it would look like.

Comment: Unfortunately this feature is not available in Google Forms, you can submit a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=978479&template=1644354)